# In a database connection, what Class.forName does?

Tags: java, android, sql-server

I saw in the tutorials use of "Class.forName". Please let me know what does it do, and if this code will work properly?

```
 public class Conexao {
    String ip = "ip";
    String class = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    String bd = "nomeBD";
    String username = "UserName";
    String password = "password";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection CONN() {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn = null;
        String ConnURL;
        try {
            Class.forName(class);
            ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";" + "databaseName=" + bd + ";user=" + username + ";password=" + password + ";";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.e("ERROR", se.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: It defines which Driver class need to use for connection.

Comment: @mohammadReza Sorry, I am new at java programing so I might sound stupid, but what is Driver class for?

Comment: Driver class enables java application to interact with the database. like your provided class=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

Comment: one more question. Is net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver  universal or do i need to use it for my server specifically?

Comment: Driver class depends on you database.

Answer (score 0):

don't see error message, and it may be formmatted incorrectly. usually i write :

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/samp_db";
...
DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
....
```

Comment: sorry,I thought it was a mistake.